# Codename one Geofencing not firing

Tags: android, ios, location, codenameone, geofencing

I'm trying to implement geofencing to my codename one app. I do everything as given in the example on github but my entered and exit methods don't seem to be firing. I included GPlayServices in the build hints as well as android.playService.* and ios.locationUsageDescription.

I've tried testing it with both and ios and android device.

Below is my code

In the onStart() method

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    u = new UIBuilder();
    Display.getInstance().lockOrientation(true);

    Location loc = new Location();
    loc.setLatitude(-26.15739);
    loc.setLongitude(28.127099999999928);
    Geofence gf = new Geofence("test", loc, 1000, 100000);

 LocationManager.getLocationManager().addGeoFencing(GeofenceListenerImpl.class, gf);

    if (Preferences.get("userId", "error").equals("error")) {
        setUpLoginForm();
    } else {
        setUpMainPage();
    }
}
```

The implementation

```
public class GeofenceListenerImpl implements GeofenceListener {

public GeofenceListenerImpl() {

}

public void onExit(String id) {
    if(Display.getInstance().isMinimized()) {
        LocalNotification ln = new LocalNotification();
        ln.setId("LnMessage1");
        ln.setAlertTitle("Welcome");
        ln.setAlertBody("Thanks for arriving! isminimized");
        Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(ln, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
    } else {
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Dialog.show("Welcome", "Thanks for arriving notminimized ", "OK", null);
            }
        });
    }
}

public void onEntered(String id) {
    if(Display.getInstance().isMinimized()) {
        LocalNotification ln = new LocalNotification();
        ln.setId("LnMessage2");
        ln.setAlertTitle("Welcome");
        ln.setAlertBody("Thanks for arriving! isminimized");
        Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(ln,  
System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
    } else {
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                Dialog.show("Welcome", "Thanks for arriving   
notminimized ", "OK", null);
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what is the full code of your Main class?

Answer (score 1):

After digging through google I found out that I have to add the build hint: ios.background_modes=location and now when the app is opened for the first time on a device it asks the user for permission to poll their location in the background. However the geofence still isn't triggering, I'll play around with my values though. Is there a similar build hint for android? Because on an android device it still isn't even pulling the location.

Comment: It's possible that 10 meters isn't big enough to register or the coordinates aren't accurate enough. Geofencing is a very coarse API meant to run in the background so to test it you really need to move.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog My 3rd parameter is 100. So isn't it 100 metres not 10??? Or did you mean 100?

Comment: Maybe instead of using a fixed location use getCurrentLocationSync()?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I can't. I don't want to geofence the user's current location, I want to geofence certain places in a city so that the user is notified when they enter one of the places.

Comment: That's not what I meant. The code looks fine and similar to our test cases. The only thing I can't verify is the coordinates, by using the values you get from getCurrentLocationSync() you effectively guarantee correct on-device coordinates and you can also then compare them to the ones that you hardcoded and see where the discrepancy happened. If this fails with the getCurrentLocationSync() it tells us one thing and if it succeeds for that case it tells us something else...

Comment: @ShaiAlmog So must I geofence the coordinates returned from getCurrentLocationSync() ??? or must I just pull those coordinates and display them in order to compare them?